# Has anyone built and installed a kernel for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS?

Tags: kernel, make, source

Has anyone:

Successfully downloaded the kernel source?

Successfully installed a built kernel without it crashing on startup?

For Ubuntu 18.04.1?

I managed to use synaptic to get

```
linux-source version 4.15.0.36.39
linux-source-4.15.0 version 4.15.0.36.39
```

I copied the tarball `linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2` to my home directory.

Unzipped it and made it using (after installing libncurses)

```
make menuconfig
copy .config to .config.bak
make mrproper
copy .config.bak to .config
make dep
make clean 
make bzImage
make modules
make modules_install 
make install
```

The kernel builds but after reset it tries to boot kernel 4.15.8 and fails because it cannot find a memory target.

Using the alternative method of downloading source `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)` [fails for this reason](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397649)

As someone who maintains a driver 18.04.1 is a useless release thus far.

Comment: Are there any additional steps you've taken that you could add for clarification?  For example, can you describe adding these as options in your bootloader?  Did you make sure to update `initrd` as well?  Did you make adjustments to the kernel configuration before compilation?  Have you ever build any other kernel and successfully installed it in the past?  As a maintainer, sure to check out new Ubuntu betas to get up to speed early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The method of kernel compilation I used works for 16.04 LTS but not 18.04.

To my shock and horror there is an [intallation guide that details how to compile an 18.04 kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/install.en.pdf)

Apart from the red face. Everything is fine and the installed kernel appears to boot and operate correctly.

So I will look for the installation guide when 20.04 LTS arrives.